# mysql sum values of field, according to other fields restrictions

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table of birthday and day, each new day will add a new record for all birthday, and the age is (date minus birthday).
Also, every new date, a new birthday is created with the same day, and the age is 0.
The following table is an example:

```
Age | BirthDay     | Date         | Users
---------------------------------------------
0   | 2017-01-01   | 2017-01-01   | 100
1   | 2017-01-01   | 2017-01-02   | 70
2   | 2017-01-01   | 2017-01-03   | 50
0   | 2017-01-02   | 2017-01-02   | 40  
1   | 2017-01-02   | 2017-01-03   | 10
0   | 2017-01-03   | 2017-01-03   | 50
```

Now, i want to know the sum of users at age 0 for every birthday that reached that date, group by age.

Result:

```
Age | Age0Sum
--------------
0   | 190
1   | 140
2   | 100
```

Explanation:

- Age 0 -> all birthdays has values in their day 0, so Age0Sum is the sum of the Age=0 number of users => 100 + 40 + 50
- Age 1 -> birthdays 2017-01-01 + 2017-01-02 has reached age 1, so Age0Sum will be theirs amount of users where day were at day 0 => 100 + 40
- Age 2 -> only one birthday date (2017-01-01) reached age 2, so their Age0Sum will be only the users from that birthday at age 0 => 100

I've tried a lot of things, trying more right now, but nothing came to concrete solution or right way.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't understand the logic applied. It seems to have something to do with either the minimum date or minimum birthdate or maximum date or maximum birthdate found in the table. Correct? If so which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say the table name is UsersTable.

```
SELECT 
    u1.Age,
    SUM(u2.Users)
FROM
    UsersTable AS ut1
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        BirthDay, Users
    FROM
        UsersTable
    WHERE
        Age = 0) AS ut2 ON ut1.BirthDay = ut2.BirthDay
GROUP BY Age
ORDER BY Age;
```

The inner select will get the number of users for each Birthday at Age = 0.
Then, The join with it will get all records who reached that group age, and sum there age from pervious select.